# How to call a method with string arguments using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Can any tell me how to call a method if the method argument is of String type using reflection. I have given the code below , **please guide me**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Use `yourMethod.invoke(yourObject, yourStringArgument)` ?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Comment: No Code provided BOSS....!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is simple example for you:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example e = new Example();
        try {
            Method method = e.getClass().getMethod("callMe", String.class);
            method.invoke(e, "s");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public void callMe(String param){
        System.out.println("called with param ="+param);
    }

}
```

Also read [tutorial for reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: For quite some years, `getMethod()` has been varargs - you can drop the Class array syntax, ie `getMethod("callMe", String.class)` works... UPDATE: Thanks @Peter :)

Comment: @Bohemian yes, in the same way that invoke uses var-args.  They were adding in Java 5.0 in 2004. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example, I'll use the `parse(String)` method from a `SimpleDateFormat` object:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Method parseMethod = SimpleDateFormat.class.getMethod("parse", String.class); 
// Or use: parseMethod = df.getClass().getMethod("parse", String.class);
Object result = parseMethod.invoke(df, "2013-1-1");
```

Comment: package com.java.examples;

public class MethodClassJunit {

 public static String printTest1(String a, String b)
 {
  System.out.println(a +","+ b);
  return null;
 }

}